How do I configure MailU to work with Authelia& Traefik?
I've been trying to setup MailU to work with Authelia via Traefik, but the guide for Traefik on the MailU site is old, stubby and uses Traefik v2. I'm using Traefik 3, Authelia, MailU in 3 separate docker-compose files with the same external network. Still trying to make MailU authenticate using Authelia instead of it's internal login system. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.
My main problem is the docker-compose.yml syntax for MailU.
